# Django get_queryset filtering with multiple select

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-filter

I doing a form of filtering by the foreignkey field with two search conditions: OR and AND and multiple choices.

**forms.py**

```
class EmployeeSkillFilter(forms.ModelForm):
    skills = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Technology.objects.all(), )

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['skills']
```

**templates.py**

```
<form  method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="and" value="AND"> Choice and<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="or" value="OR"> Choice OR<br>

          {{ skill_filter }}
    <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-info" type="button">Go!</button>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
class AccountList(AuthorizedMixin, ListView):

    model = Employee
    template_name = 'employee_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        condition_and = self.request.GET.get('and', None)
        condition_or = self.request.GET.get('or', None)
        skill = self.request.GET.get('skills', None)
        if condition_and and skill:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(skills__name_id=skill) ??????

        if condition_or and tech:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(
                Q(skills__name_id=skill) |
                Q(skills__name_id=skill)
            ) ?????
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.all()
```

My urls looks like

```
localhost://....or=OR&skills=5&skills=4&skills=3
```

The problem is that when I select multiple objects in a form, I don't know how to pass them all to the condition

```
skills__name_id=skill
```

Comment: What is `request.GET.get('skills')`? What do you get from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup, and in case of and logic, count the number of matches:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class AccountList(AuthorizedMixin, ListView):

    model = Employee
    template_name = 'employee_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        condition_and = self.request.GET.get('and', None)
        condition_or = self.request.GET.get('and', None)
        skills = self.request.GET.getlist('skills')
        if condition_and:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(
                skills__in=skills
            ).annotate(
                nskills=Count('skills')
            ).filter(
                nskills=len(skills)
            )
        elif condition_or:
            object_list = self.model.objects.filter(
                skills__in=skills
            ).distinct()
        else:
            object_list = self.model.objects.all()
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I trying you code and OR condition working good, but AND doesn't produce any results.

Comment: I also made a mistake in the question by specifying an incorrect `get('and', None)`  value in **views.py** code for the OR condition. I fixed the question but it also does not work with this AND.

Comment: @Jekson: I made a type (`skill` instead of `skill`). The `and` evidently means the employee must have all technologies as skills. Are you sure that is the case?

Comment: my inattention, in your code everything is correct, the problem was in my template.html. Excellent answer!

Comment: @Jekson: by using a `JOIN` on the skills if there are multiple skills that match, it would mean that the employee is returned once *per* matched skill. So if you have an employee that has skills 2,5,7, and 9, and you select `3, 5, 6, 7`, it will be returned two times. The `.distinct()` prevents that: an employee will only be returned once.